# 3D mesh explosion in Cocos2D-X

Tags: 3d, cocos2d-x

I am developing a 3D game with Cocos2D-X. I want to implement the functionality of exploding 3D mesh file into its components. I found that Cocos2D-X currently does not include the feature of destructible mesh similar to other game engines. As per the 3D documentation on Cocos2D-X website, Cocos2D-X currently supports Particle Universe Editor for creation of the 3D particle effects, but the domain for download link of Particle Universe Editor is expired (Mirrors also lead to expired domain). I am able to use the in-built explosion 3D particle system in Cocos2D-X, but I want the texture of exploded particles to be the same as the mesh texture.

I have the following queries:

1) Does anyone have the working link for downloading the Particle Universe Editor?

2) Are there any other alternative tools/plug-ins for creating 3D mesh explosion for Cocos2D-X?

3) Also, are there any other good approaches for implementing 3D mesh explosion functionality in Cocos2D-X?

I’d appreciate any suggestions on this issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) [Here](http://www.filedropper.com/puniverse) is a Particle Universe Editor (link found on [discuss.cocos2d-x.org](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/do-you-have-particle-universe-editor-please-share-it/25955/8)). Developer's page seems to not work anymore ([link](http://www.fxpression.com)).

2), 3) [Here](https://github.com/adamkotkowski/cocos2dx-explode-animation) is a sample 3D mesh explosion animation.

Probably the best effect you will get combining 3D particles and mesh explosion animation.

[image: cocos2d-x 3D mesh explosion animation]